# Combine multiples table to a new one

Tags: postgresql, query

I apologize, I am not sure how to word this question. It probably has been answered somewhere, but I couldn't find it if so.

I have three tables that I want to combine in one using a common `id` column, with empty rows here and there.

#### table1

```
 id | col1 
----|------ 
  1 | 23.4 
  3 | 13.4 
  4 |  7.6
```

#### table2

```
 id | col2 
----|------ 
  1 | 12.2 
  2 | 17.1
```

#### table3

```
 id | col3 
----|------ 
  1 | 22.2 
  2 | 14.1 
  5 | 10.8
```

I want to create a fourth table table4:

```
 id | col1 | col2 | col3 
----|------|------|------ 
  1 | 23.4 | 12.2 | 22.2 
  2 | NULL | 17.2 | 14.1 
  3 | 13.4 | NULL | NULL 
  4 | 7.6  | NULL | NULL 
  5 | NULL | NULL | 10.8
```

I'm stumped as to how to approach this problem honestly.

Comment: You need to use `full outer join`s.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.id,b.id,c.id), COALESCE(a.col1,'NULL'), COALESCE(b.col2,'NULL'), COALESCE(c.col3,'NULL')
  FROM table1 a
  FULL OUTER JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id
  FULL OUTER JOIN table3 c ON b.id=c.id;
```

or, if you want blanks instead of strings:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.id,b.id,c.id), a.col1, b.col2, c.col3
  FROM table1 a
  FULL OUTER JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id
  FULL OUTER JOIN table3 c ON b.id=c.id;
```

Comment: If an ID exists in `table1` and `table3` but not `table2`, you will end up having two rows with that ID in the output, because the `table3` joining condition doesn't take that case into account. Instead of just `b.id = c.id` you could use something like `COALESCE(a.id, b.id) = c.id`, or maybe `c.id IN (a.id, b.id)`.